# Error in sending parameters to controller through @Url.Action in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url-action

I am working on an `MVC` project and I was trying to send some parameters to my controller in `JQuery` using `@Url.Action`.

HTML code:

```
<button class="btn btn-white btn-sm demo1" data-id='@item.TeamID'>Delete</button>
```

JQuery Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.demo1').click(function (event) {
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this team!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            }, function () {
                var data = event.data;
                var id = data.id;
                var url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Teams", new { id = "__param__" })';
                window.location.href = url.replace('__param__', encodeURIComponent(id));

                swal("Deleted!", "Your team has been deleted.", "success");
            });
        });
    });
```

However, the Delete method in the Teams controller is not being triggered. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**
The HTML button is placed inside a `foreach` loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamName)
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamInits)
          </td>
          <td>
              @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TeamID }, new { @class = "btn btn-white btn-sm" })
              <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm demo1" data-id='@item.TeamID'>Delete</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
 }
```

Comment: You are binding event handler with class `demo3`

Comment: Sorry i did a mistake while copying the code. In fact I am building an event handler with class demo1. I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property or `.data()` to read the custom `data-*` prefixed attribute value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.demo1').click(function (event) {            
        var id = this.dataset.id; 
        //OR
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        //Rest of the code
        swal();
    });
});
```

Comment: `var id = $(this).data('id');` worked for me, but the id is returned as null to the controller. Please note that the html button is placed inside a foreach loop. Check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I usually Try the below code trick. When anything goes wrong like this.

Add the below code in you `Global.asax.cs` file and Put debugger inside the method, so that it Will be triggered when ever exception occurs.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    string ex = exception.Message; // Here you will get to know what is going wrong
}
```

The exception message or the stack trace will provide the enough information details to fix the errors.

Even though if its request from Jquery / Razor Html page errors, you will have enough info.

Hope this helps!!!